Unable to print to cups networked printer from one Ubuntu 24.04 box after reboot
I have a HP Laserjet M1319f MFD printer scanner that is connected via USB to a Raspberry Pi4 running Ubuntu 24.04 server and networked via CUPS for access from all of my other computers. This works fine across the network, even got SANE to work for scanning. However, one computer will lose the ability to print to this networked printer after every reboot. This forces me to remove the printer and readd it, after which it works as expected. This is not the biggest deal in the world, but I have employees that are not the saviest when it comes to computers and I would like to avoid the phone calls.
I am including the hwinfo --short output from the offending computer:
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz, 3428 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz, 3300 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz, 3437 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz, 3233 MHz
keyboard:
                       Logitech Unifying Receiver
  /dev/input/event2    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
mouse:
                       Logitech Unifying Receiver
monitor:
                       Lenovo AIO
graphics card:
                       Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
sound:
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
storage:
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
network:
  eno1                 Intel 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection
network interface:
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  eno1                 Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             ST3500413AS
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/sda3            Partition
cdrom:
  /dev/sr0             HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT30N
usb controller:
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
                       Intel Q57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
                       Intel 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
                       Intel 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0
                       Intel Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
                       Intel 82801 PCI Bridge
                       Intel Core Processor DRAM Controller
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
                       Intel 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
                       Intel Core Processor QPI Link 0
                       Intel Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3
hub:
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Huasheng Electronics 4-port hub [Maxxter ACT-HUB2-4P, HS8836, iSoul ultra-slim]
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Huasheng Electronics 4-port hub [Maxxter ACT-HUB2-4P, HS8836, iSoul ultra-slim]
memory:
                       Main Memory
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
                       Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
                       Z-Star Microelectronics Lenovo ThinkCentre Web Camera

And the output of uname -a:
Linux store-ThinkCentre-M90z 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 21:49:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have started from scratch on the CUPS server, rebuilding the entire thing from a fresh install. I have done the same with the offending computer as well to no avail.
I don't know what to do next. Any thoughts or theories would be greatly appreciated.

On the failig system, Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware and start the servers) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.
